# No scientific notation and rounding with double

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

I want to round a number to 6 places and I don't want it to be displayed using scientific notation. I am using this code to round the decimal to 6 places but if the value is really small, it is still displaying it using scientific notation. I know that I can use the number formatter (displayed below as well) to remove the scientific notation but if I do that then it is returns a string so I cannot round a string to a certain number of decimal places. If I do the rounding first, that still doesn't work in all scenarios. It still shows some numbers without rounding. What is the best way to achieve this? It should work in all different scenarios where numbers are infinitely long or repeating

```
extension Double {
    // Rounds the double to decimal places value
    func rounded(toPlaces places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
       return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}




let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
numberFormatter.number(from:"")
```

I tried to use this code

```
let currentValue = 1/2.3344 //answer is 0.42837559972584...
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6
guard let finalNum = numberFormatter.number(from: String(describing: currentValue)) else {return nil}
text = String (describing: finalNum)
```

I want it to display 0.428375. The value rounded to 6 decimal places.

When the current value is this: `let currentValue = 1/233442` which is 0.00000428371... I want it to display 0.000004. The decimal rounded to 6 decimal places and not in scientific notation.

When the current value is this: `let currentValue = 1/2334429`  I want it to display 0 because that is the value rounded to 6 decimal places.

Comment: *"but if I do that then it is returns a string"* – scientific notation is *only* used when converting a number to a string.

Comment: And of course `Double` *cannot* represent all decimal fractions exactly, which may be part of your problem.

Comment: yes but this returns a string of numbers that go on forever but I want to only display the number to the first 6 places. If a string is returned that is too long then I would still have to cut it down. I know I can manipulate the string but I feel like there is a better way for me to do this.

Comment: NumberFormatter has properties like maximumFractionDigits to control the conversion ...

Comment: I tried this and it also didn't work `let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter(); numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal; numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6`

Comment: Edit your question, show what you did, what input data you have, what output you got and what you expected. – In other words, a [mcve].

Comment: I just edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `number(from: someString)` method converts a string to a number,
you want it the other way around:

```
let currentEntry = 1/2.3344

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6

guard let text = numberFormatter.string(for: currentEntry) else {
    // ...
}
print(text) // 0.428376
```

Note that your `String(describing:)` conversions only hide the problem.
You really should avoid `String(describing:)` (even if the compiler suggests
it as a Fix-it!), it almost never does what you need.

Comment: Awesome! It looks like this was a dumb error on my part. Thanks for the tip about the `String(describing:)` I will definitely keep that in mind.